# How to connect the mirrored bone to the central bone?

Tags: armature

[image]

I appended a suffix of .L to the name of a bone on one side, then executed armature -> symmetrize to mirror the bones.

However, the copied bone is not connected to the central spine, and if rotated in pose mode it will move away from the spine.

How can I make the copied bone connect to the backbone?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After activating connected in edit mode, the bones are connected.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question to find and an easy one to have; I almost asked it myself. With noprops' answer, I figured it out:

1. Make sure all bones are part of the same armature. If they're not, select them and join them (Ctrl + J).
2. Click the root of the leg bone chain, a.k.a. the bone you want to connect to the spine bone chain, then Shift + Click the spine bone you want it connected to.
3. Now press Ctrl + P and set the parent. Connected is what you asked for, but I like offset because it helps avoid making intermediate bones.

What you're doing here is parenting one bone chain to another by setting the parent of a bone manually (usually it's automatic when extruding from other bones).